# How do you construct a great circle arc that best fits (in the least-squared distance sense) three or more points on the surface of a sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, spherical-trigonometry

I am interested in solving a celestial navigation for myself.  This reference https://aa.usno.navy.mil/downloads/reports/Kaplan1996b.pdf by George Kaplan describes how the US Navy’s STELLA software uses a best-fit approach to not only determine latitude and longitude, but also ship’s course and speed, from several celestial observations made over an interval of time.  I do not understand where equation (1) in that reference came from, so I’m trying to determine the solution to a simpler, related problem: how to find the great-circle that best fits three points on a spherical Earth that are not necessarily ‘collinear’ in the spherical trigonometry sense.

Specifically, given points with lat and lon ($\phi_1$, $\lambda_1$), ($\phi_2$, $\lambda_2$), and ($\phi_3$, $\lambda_3$), I want to find an equation relating $\phi$ and $\lambda$ that describes a great circle.  If $d_i$ is the (perpendicular) shortest distance from point ($\phi_i$, $\lambda_i$) and the great circle, the great circle should be the one that minimizes the overall root-sum-squared-distances $d_{rss} = \sqrt{d_1^2 + d_2^2 + d_3^2}$.

The squaring of the distances is not crucial to the spirit of the problem, but like a least-squares best fit line on a plane, I imagine that it guarantees all the terms are positive and is easier to work with than absolute values, as in $d = |d_1| + |d_2| + |d_3|$.  I recognize that the least-square process on a plan actually minimizes the sum of the *vertical* squared distances for convenience, but I don’t see that there’s an obvious analogous quantity on the surface of a sphere, so I choose to minimize the *shortest* squared distances between points and the great circle, which are great circle arcs perpendicular to the best fit great circle.

The only similar question I found was this, but the only answer seems to be more of a suggestion, and I am wholly unfamiliar with tensor-related math: [Line of best fit on the surface of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525434/line-of-best-fit-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere)

Thank you for any insight you might be willing to share.

Comment: Since a great circle is centered at the origin, you can first find the best fitting plane passing through the origin to the given points.

Comment: Thank you for that idea!  That would effectively answer it.  It seems like the distance being minimized would likely be the straight line segments from each of the three points to the plane, vice the short perpendicular great circle segments to the best fit great circle.  I don’t know if the intersection of the plane and sphere would minimize both distances, but it would surely be very close and effectively identical.  Thank you